# Cannot create table in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to add a table to my schema in MySQL workbench and I keep getting an error.

**Message Log:**

```
Executing:
CREATE TABLE `TestVisual`.`arc` (
    `arcid` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT '',
    `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`arcid`)  COMMENT '');

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COMMENT '')' at line 4
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `TestVisual`.`arc` (
    `arcid` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT '',
    `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`arcid`)  COMMENT '')
```

I have tried to follow a tutorial but I still get the error. There are other tables already on this server and I am able to change their data along with add and delete columns. I am also on the root user.

Comment: [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/755ef/1/0),  is  this your actual code? Or you concatenate string from parts or quote everything with `'`

Comment: your command works on my box if I remove the db specified, naturally

Comment: It is the code that is generated from the MySQL workbench program.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running? `COMMENT` wasn't allowed in index options until 5.5.

Comment: Compare http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html with http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html.

Comment: That was it Barmar, I removed COMMENT from it and it works now

Comment: That is actually a bug that has been fixed in the upcoming release. MySQL Workbench created empty comments, even though it wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

[Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) answered it above in the comments. This server is using an older version of MySQL so there are not allowed to be COMMENT in the sql. Deleted them and it worked fine.

Comment: Since you mentioned it was generated code, perhaps from a model, under  Preferences set Modeling->MySQL->"Default Target MySQL Version" to your MySQL version, and it should generate more appropriate code.